# problem with mongoose virtual populate (populated field is missing)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

i was using mongoose in my project with typescript when i add virtual called **subdomains** to populate the data from another collection its working without error but i can't print the populated data directly, i can only access the value using **console.log((r as any).subdomains)** but when print the **console.log(r as any)** there is no field called subdomains,please check example 1 and example 2

```
export interface IDomain{
    domain:string
    owner:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
}

const domainSchema = new Schema<IDomain>({
    domain:{type:String,required:true},
    owner:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,required:true},

})
domainSchema.virtual("subdomains",{
    ref:"DomainMonitor",
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'owner'})
```

**Querying the database | example 1**

```
Domain.findOne({owner:"633ebe32d0733c0a8eb4f8d6"}).populate("subdomains").then(r=>{
        console.log(domains)
})
```

**output | example 1**

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6342fa2d4b730f004704eb45"),
  domain: 'dummy.com',
  __v: 0,
  owner: new ObjectId("633ebe32d0733c0a8eb4f8d6")
}
```

**Query the database | example 2**

```
Domain.findOne({owner:"633ebe32d0733c0a8eb4f8d6"}).populate("subdomains").then(r=>{
        const domains= (r as any).subdomains
        console.log(domains)
    })
```

**output | example 2**

```
[{
  _id: new ObjectId("6342fa314b730f004704eb47"),
  owner: new ObjectId("6342fa2d4b730f004704eb45"),
  subdomain: [
    'dummy',
  ],
  wildcard: [ '*.dummy.com', '*.dummy.com' ],
  __v: 1
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach where you represent your schema as object, *not as JSON* (using .-operator) is the following:

```js
// create a new schema
const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        channel: { type: String },
        content: { type: String, required: true },
        moderator: { type: Number },
    },
    // Add this to your Schema
    {
        toObject: { virtuals: true },
        // alternatively: toJSON: { virtuals: true}, if you want your output as json
    }
);
```

```
// Approach 2:
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  domain: { type:String, required:true },
  owner: { type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, required:true }
});
mySchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true })
```

[Mongoose Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) says:

> Keep in mind that virtuals are **not** included in toJSON() and toObject() output by default. If you want populate virtuals to show up when using functions like Express' res.json() function or console.log(), set the virtuals: true option on your schema's toJSON and toObject() options.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is stated in the mongoose documentation (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html):

> If you use toJSON() or toObject() mongoose will not include virtuals by default. This includes the output of calling JSON.stringify() on a Mongoose document, because JSON.stringify() calls toJSON(). Pass { virtuals: true } to either toObject() or toJSON().

Basically your `console.log` statement makes a call to `toJSON` and does not include virtuals by default.

You can include the following in your schema definition in order to include virtuals in your `toJSON` calls:

```
domainSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });
```